# Changing .Net assembly name at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to load an assembly with reflection and rename it. Of course I cannot just rename the file: I must also change its internal information.

How can I do so?

Comment: May I ask you what is your actual use case?

Comment: Maybe the actual problem could be solved with an AppDomain (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6s0z09xw.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible.  The name of an `Assembly` is immutable once loaded into the CLR.  You would need to rename it before it was loaded

Answer (score 0):

You can probably copy the assembly into a new dynamic assembly and then load the dynamic assembly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ffc3x75.aspx

But if there's another way to accomplish what you are looking for I'd recommend exploring that option, creating assemblies at run time is not going to be easy.